# How to call Makefile recipe/rule multiple times?

Tags: makefile, latex, pdflatex, biblatex

With the following example:

```
.PHONY: hook1 hook2

# Default target
all: hook1 hook2 hook1
    echo "Calling all"

hook1:
    echo "Calling hook1"

hook2:
    echo "Calling hook2"
```

I got the output:

```
$ make
echo "Calling hook1"
Calling hook1
echo "Calling hook2"
Calling hook2
echo "Calling all"
Calling all
```

But I would expect it to call the rule `hook1` two times. This is because on Latex, I need to call the same program with the same command line, multiple times. Then I would like to reuse the make rules. For example, I would expect the above minimal code to be ran as:

```
$ make
echo "Calling hook1"
Calling hook1
echo "Calling hook2"
Calling hook2
echo "Calling hook1"
Calling hook1
echo "Calling all"
Calling all
```

Which call the same rule twice. This is code bellow my full main Makefile code, if anyone is interested. I tried to create the dummy rules `pdflatex_hook1` and `pdflatex_hook2` so I could do the call hierarchy `pdflatex_hook biber_hook pdflatex_hook`, but this do not fooled `make` and it still ignoring my last call to `pdflatex_hook2`:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123241/makefile-as-an-executable-script-with-shebang
ECHOCMD:=/bin/echo -e

# The main latex file
THESIS_MAIN_FILE = modelomain.tex

# This will be the pdf generated
THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME = thesis

# This is the folder where the temporary files are going to be
CACHE_FOLDER = setup/cache

# Find all files ending with `main.tex`
LATEX_SOURCE_FILES := $(wildcard *main.tex)

# Create a new variable within all `LATEX_SOURCE_FILES` file names ending with `.pdf`
LATEX_PDF_FILES := $(LATEX_SOURCE_FILES:.tex=.pdf)


# GNU Make silent by default
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005166/gnu-make-silent-by-default
MAKEFLAGS += --silent
.PHONY: clean pdflatex_hook1 pdflatex_hook2 %.pdf %.tex

# How do I write the 'cd' command in a makefile?
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789594/how-do-i-write-the-cd-command-in-a-makefile
.ONESHELL:

# Default target
all: biber


##
## Usage:
##   make <target>
##
## Targets:
##   biber             build the main file with bibliography pass
##   pdflatex          build the main file with no bibliography pass
##

# Print the usage instructions
# https://gist.github.com/prwhite/8168133
help:
    @fgrep -h "##" $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | fgrep -v fgrep | sed -e 's/\\$$//' | sed -e 's/##//'


# Where to find official (!) and extended documentation for tex/latex's commandline options (especially -interaction modes)?
# https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91592/where-to-find-official-and-extended-documentation-for-tex-latexs-commandlin
PDF_LATEX_COMMAND = pdflatex --time-statistics --synctex=1 -halt-on-error -file-line-error
LATEX = $(PDF_LATEX_COMMAND)\
--interaction=batchmode\
-jobname="$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME)"\
-output-directory="$(CACHE_FOLDER)"\
-aux-directory="$(CACHE_FOLDER)"


# Run pdflatex, biber, pdflatex
biber: biber_hook pdflatex_hook2

    # Calculate the elapsed seconds and print them to the screen
    . ./setup/scripts/timer_calculator.sh
    showTheElapsedSeconds "$(current_dir)"

# Internally called rule which does not attempt to show the elapsed time
biber_hook: pdflatex_hook1

    # Creates the shell variable `current_dir` within the current folder path
    $(eval current_dir := $(shell pwd)) echo $(current_dir) > /dev/null

    biber "$(CACHE_FOLDER)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME)"


# This rule will be called for every latex file and pdf associated
pdflatex: $(LATEX_PDF_FILES)

    # Calculate the elapsed seconds and print them to the screen
    . ./setup/scripts/timer_calculator.sh
    showTheElapsedSeconds "$(current_dir)"

# Not show the elapsed time when called internally
pdflatex_hook1: $(LATEX_PDF_FILES)
pdflatex_hook2: $(LATEX_PDF_FILES)


%.pdf: %.tex

    # Start counting the compilation time and import its shell functions
    . ./setup/scripts/timer_calculator.sh

    # Creates the shell variable `current_dir` within the current folder path
    $(eval current_dir := $(shell pwd)) echo $(current_dir) > /dev/null

    @$(LATEX) $<
    cp $(CACHE_FOLDER)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME).pdf $(current_dir)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME).pdf
```

Here when I call the rule `make biber` I got the output:

```
$ make biber
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400)
entering extended mode
gross execution time: 62751 ms

user mode: 58406 ms, kernel mode: 1359 ms, total: 59765
INFO - This is Biber 2.7
INFO - Logfile is 'setup/cache/thesis.blg'
INFO - Reading 'setup/cache/thesis.bcf'
INFO - Found 14 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'modeloreferences.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'modeloreferences.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'pt-BR' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'pt-BR' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'pt-BR'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'pt-BR'
INFO - Writing 'setup/cache/thesis.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to setup/cache/thesis.bbl
Could not calculate the seconds to run
```

Which is missing the second call to the rule `pdflatex_hook2`, only the first call to `pdflatex_hook1` is being performed.`

I already know about `latexmk` and use it, but for `biber` above I would like to do these calls as they are. For `latexmk` I use this recipe/rule:

```
thesis: $(THESIS_MAIN_FILE)

    # Start counting the compilation time and import its shell functions
    . ./setup/scripts/timer_calculator.sh

    # Creates the shell variable `current_dir` within the current folder path
    $(eval current_dir := $(shell pwd)) echo $(current_dir) > /dev/null

    # What is the difference between “-interaction=nonstopmode” and “-halt-on-error”?
    # https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258814/what-is-the-difference-between-interaction-nonstopmode-and-halt-on-error
    #
    # What reasons (if any) are there for compiling in interactive mode?
    # https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25267/what-reasons-if-any-are-there-for-compiling-in-interactive-mode
    latexmk \
    -pdf \
    -silent \
    -jobname="$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME)" \
    -output-directory="$(CACHE_FOLDER)" \
    -aux-directory="$(CACHE_FOLDER)" \
    -pdflatex="$(PDF_LATEX_COMMAND) --interaction=batchmode" \
    -use-make $(THESIS_MAIN_FILE)

    # Copy the generated PDF file from the cache folder
    cp $(CACHE_FOLDER)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME).pdf $(current_dir)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME).pdf

    # Calculate the elapsed seconds and print them to the screen
    showTheElapsedSeconds "$(current_dir)"
```

---

Related questions:

1. [Change a make variable, and call another rule, from a recipe in same Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382846/change-a-make-variable-and-call-another-rule-from-a-recipe-in-same-makefile)
2. [How to manually call another target from a make target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377297/how-to-manually-call-another-target-from-a-make-target)
3. [multiple targets from one recipe and parallel execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822435/multiple-targets-from-one-recipe-and-parallel-execution)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make recipe execute twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654681/make-recipe-execute-twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your initial question:

```
.PHONY: hook1 hook2

# Default target
all: hook1a hook2 hook1b
    echo "Calling all"

hook1a hook1b:
    echo "Calling hook1"

hook2:
    echo "Calling hook2"
```

Produces the following output:

```
echo "Calling hook1"
Calling hook1
echo "Calling hook2"
Calling hook2
echo "Calling hook1"
Calling hook1
echo "Calling all"
Calling all
```

As illustrated in [make recipe execute twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654681/make-recipe-execute-twice)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@David White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2782424) answer I fixed my main script with the double recursion:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123241/makefile-as-an-executable-script-with-shebang
ECHOCMD:=/bin/echo -e

# The main latex file
THESIS_MAIN_FILE = modelomain.tex

# This will be the pdf generated
THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME = thesis

# This is the folder where the temporary files are going to be
CACHE_FOLDER = setup/cache

# Find all files ending with `main.tex`
LATEX_SOURCE_FILES := $(wildcard *main.tex)

# Create a new variable within all `LATEX_SOURCE_FILES` file names ending with `.pdf`
LATEX_PDF_FILES := $(LATEX_SOURCE_FILES:.tex=.pdf)


# GNU Make silent by default
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005166/gnu-make-silent-by-default
MAKEFLAGS += --silent
.PHONY: clean biber pdflatex_hook1 pdflatex_hook2

# How do I write the 'cd' command in a makefile?
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789594/how-do-i-write-the-cd-command-in-a-makefile
.ONESHELL:

# Default target
all: thesis


##
## Usage:
##   make <target>
##
## Targets:
##   all        call the `thesis` make rule
##   biber      build the main file with bibliography pass
##   latex      build the main file with no bibliography pass
##   thesis     completely build the main file with minimum output logs
##   verbose    completely build the main file with maximum output logs
##

# Print the usage instructions
# https://gist.github.com/prwhite/8168133
help:
    @fgrep -h "##" $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | fgrep -v fgrep | sed -e 's/\\$$//' | sed -e 's/##//'


# Where to find official (!) and extended documentation for tex/latex's commandline options (especially -interaction modes)?
# https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91592/where-to-find-official-and-extended-documentation-for-tex-latexs-commandlin
PDF_LATEX_COMMAND = pdflatex --time-statistics --synctex=1 -halt-on-error -file-line-error
LATEX = $(PDF_LATEX_COMMAND)\
--interaction=batchmode\
-jobname="$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME)"\
-output-directory="$(CACHE_FOLDER)"\
-aux-directory="$(CACHE_FOLDER)"


# Run pdflatex, biber, pdflatex
biber: start_timer pdflatex_hook1 biber_hook pdflatex_hook2

    # Creates the shell variable `current_dir` within the current folder path
    $(eval current_dir := $(shell pwd)) echo $(current_dir) > /dev/null

    # Copies the PDF to the current folder
    cp $(CACHE_FOLDER)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME).pdf $(current_dir)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME).pdf

    # Calculate the elapsed seconds and print them to the screen
    . ./setup/scripts/timer_calculator.sh
    showTheElapsedSeconds "$(current_dir)"


start_timer:

    # Start counting the elapsed seconds to print them to the screen later
    . ./setup/scripts/timer_calculator.sh


# Internally called rule which does not attempt to show the elapsed time
biber_hook:

    # Creates the shell variable `current_dir` within the current folder path
    $(eval current_dir := $(shell pwd)) echo $(current_dir) > /dev/null

    # Call biber to process the bibliography
    biber "$(CACHE_FOLDER)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME)"


# How to call Makefile recipe/rule multiple times?
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135614/how-to-call-makefile-recipe-rule-multiple-times
pdflatex_hook1 pdflatex_hook2:

    @$(LATEX) $(LATEX_SOURCE_FILES)


# This rule will be called for every latex file and pdf associated
latex: $(LATEX_PDF_FILES)

    # Calculate the elapsed seconds and print them to the screen
    . ./setup/scripts/timer_calculator.sh
    showTheElapsedSeconds "$(current_dir)"


# Dynamically generated recipes for all PDF and latex files
%.pdf: %.tex

    # Start counting the compilation time and import its shell functions
    . ./setup/scripts/timer_calculator.sh

    # Creates the shell variable `current_dir` within the current folder path
    $(eval current_dir := $(shell pwd)) echo $(current_dir) > /dev/null

    @$(LATEX) $<
    cp $(CACHE_FOLDER)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME).pdf $(current_dir)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME).pdf


thesis: $(THESIS_MAIN_FILE)

    # Start counting the compilation time and import its shell functions
    . ./setup/scripts/timer_calculator.sh

    # Creates the shell variable `current_dir` within the current folder path
    $(eval current_dir := $(shell pwd)) echo $(current_dir) > /dev/null

    # What is the difference between “-interaction=nonstopmode” and “-halt-on-error”?
    # https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258814/what-is-the-difference-between-interaction-nonstopmode-and-halt-on-error
    #
    # What reasons (if any) are there for compiling in interactive mode?
    # https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25267/what-reasons-if-any-are-there-for-compiling-in-interactive-mode
    latexmk \
    -pdf \
    -silent \
    -jobname="$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME)" \
    -output-directory="$(CACHE_FOLDER)" \
    -aux-directory="$(CACHE_FOLDER)" \
    -pdflatex="$(PDF_LATEX_COMMAND) --interaction=batchmode" \
    -use-make $(THESIS_MAIN_FILE)

    # Copy the generated PDF file from the cache folder
    cp $(CACHE_FOLDER)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME).pdf $(current_dir)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME).pdf

    # Calculate the elapsed seconds and print them to the screen
    showTheElapsedSeconds "$(current_dir)"


verbose: $(THESIS_MAIN_FILE)

    # Start counting the compilation time and import its shell functions
    . ./setup/scripts/timer_calculator.sh

    # Creates the shell variable `current_dir` within the current folder path
    $(eval current_dir := $(shell pwd)) echo $(current_dir) > /dev/null

    # What is the difference between “-interaction=nonstopmode” and “-halt-on-error”?
    # https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258814/what-is-the-difference-between-interaction-nonstopmode-and-halt-on-error
    #
    # What reasons (if any) are there for compiling in interactive mode?
    # https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25267/what-reasons-if-any-are-there-for-compiling-in-interactive-mode
    latexmk \
    -pdf \
    -jobname="$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME)" \
    -output-directory="$(CACHE_FOLDER)" \
    -aux-directory="$(CACHE_FOLDER)" \
    -pdflatex="$(PDF_LATEX_COMMAND) --interaction=nonstopmode" \
    -use-make $(THESIS_MAIN_FILE)

    # Copy the generated PDF file from the cache folder
    cp $(CACHE_FOLDER)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME).pdf $(current_dir)/$(THESIS_OUTPUT_NAME).pdf

    # Calculate the elapsed seconds and print them to the screen
    showTheElapsedSeconds "$(current_dir)"


# Using Makefile to clean subdirectories
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007005/using-makefile-to-clean-subdirectories
#
# Exclude directory from find . command
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command
GARBAGE_TYPES := "*.gz(busy)" *.aux *.log *.pdf *.aux *.bbl *.log *.out *.toc *.dvi *.blg\
*.synctex.gz *.fdb_latexmk *.fls *.lot *.lol *.lof *.idx

DIRECTORIES_TO_CLEAN  := $(shell /bin/find -not -path "./**.git**" -not -path "./pictures**" -type d)
GARBAGE_TYPED_FOLDERS := $(foreach DIR, $(DIRECTORIES_TO_CLEAN), $(addprefix $(DIR)/,$(GARBAGE_TYPES)))

clean:
    rm -rfv $(GARBAGE_TYPED_FOLDERS)


# veryclean:
#   git clean -dxf
```