# make .SECONDEXPANSION recipe execute twice

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Using GNU make, I am trying to solve a problem similar to [make recipe execute twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654681/make-recipe-execute-twice) — that is, to have a Makefile recipe run twice.  In my case, however, the recipe is run under the `.SECONDEXPANSION` target, and the two different runs will be called with different parameters to generate different versions of the output file from the same input file.  That is, with input file `foo`, this example Makefile should be callable via `make foo.pdf` or `make foo.expanded.pdf` to build one .pdf file, or `make all` to build both .pdf files:

```
.PHONY: all

all: foo.pdf foo.expanded.pdf

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.expanded.pdf %.pdf: %
    @echo building $(basename $@)
```

Of the two solutions given in that answer, the first is unsuitable because it *always* runs the rule twice; I want it run twice when the user asks for it.

The second solution posted there is conceptually what I am looking for and have implemented in the above example Makefile, with only the small problem that it doesn't work: although the `all` target lists both .pdf files as dependencies, only one is built when `make all` is run.

Is there a way to tell GNU make to build two different files using the same rule under a `.SECONDEXPANSION`?

**EDIT:** Clarified in problem description that the same input file is used to build both versions of the output file, and modified sample Makefile to include this dependency.

**EDIT:** I would like a solution as scalable as possible; that is, it should work if the input filename contains dots, specifying additional output file `foo.reduced.pdf` should require only adjusting the targets and recipe as appropriate, etc.  This limits performing string surgery that relies on the filenames appearing exactly as given in this narrow example (e.g., changing the rule to `%.pdf: $$(firstword $$(subst ., ,$$*))` fails if the input file could be either `foo` or `foo.bar`).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with `.SECONDEXPANSION`.  You can just drop that and the problem will be the same.

Your problem is that you are using a pattern rule with multiple target patterns, and expecting that it works similar to an explicit rule with multiple targets. But it does not (and in fact you cannot have a rule with both pattern and explicit targets).

For a pattern rule with multiple target patterns, Make matches the same pattern to all the `%`, including multiple times in the targets, and then assumes that it just has to execute the recipe with that pattern once, and it will make all the matched targets.

In your case the best way is to use multiple rules (I changed your recipe because using `echo` as a Make recipe is a bad idea):

```
.PHONY: all
all: foo.expanded.pdf foo.pdf 

RECIPE = touch $@

%.expanded.pdf:
    $(RECIPE)

%.pdf:
    $(RECIPE)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  This will get the job done, but in my (hard-won) experience, duplicating code--even if the duplicated part is simple (which my actual recipe is not)--results in inconsistencies when whoever next updates the code (probably a future me who has forgotten this hack) changes one instance of `$(RECIPE)` but not the other.  This also scales poorly if other variant `.pdf`s are added, requiring a new duplicate rule for each.  Any design that calls for a comment warning future editors of duplicate code is one that should be refactored if at all possible to consolidate the duplication.

Comment: The `echo` in my example was purely for illustrative purposes, but I'd like to know why it's bad to use in a recipe.

Comment: @Targeloid what do you mean by "changing one instance by not the other" - that's what I used the canned recipe, so there is no code duplication.  About `echo` - in makefiles, a recipe should always write a file, namely, the target, this is a good design practice (you can consult Paul Smith, the maintainer of Make, if you don't believe me) and Make already prints the recipe lines. Even purely for testing purposes, it is always better to `touch` than to `echo`.

Comment: @Targeloid for example, if you used `touch`, you would have seen that running `make` second time, gives a different result!  This might have given you the answer to your question already.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [Pattern-specific Variable Values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern_002dspecific). Let's assume your recipe depends on a make variable named `BUILDFLAGS` that takes value `normal` by default and `special` for the "*expanded*" targets. Then this Makefile:

```
BUILDER    := builder
BUILDFLAGS := normal

.PHONY: all

all: foo.pdf foo.expanded.pdf

%.expanded.pdf: BUILDFLAGS := special

%.pdf:
    $(BUILDER) $(BUILDFLAGS) $@
```

should do about what you want with the same rule for all targets, plus one pattern-specific variable value declaration. Replace `builder`, `normal` and `special` with what makes sense in your case. Demo:

```
$ make foo.pdf
builder normal foo.pdf
$ make foo.expanded.pdf
builder special foo.expanded.pdf
$ make
builder normal foo.pdf
builder special foo.expanded.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer perfectly addresses what I asked but not what I needed. :)  I apologize--in simplifying the example Makefile to its bare bones, I omitted an important bone: both `foo.pdf` and `foo.expanded.pdf` depend on the same input file `foo`.  Your `%.pdf` rule works in the oversimplified example, but adding the `%` dependency allows it to build `foo.pdf` but not `foo.expanded.pdf` because there is no `foo.expanded` input file.  I'll edit the question to include this requirement.